# BeautifulSoup scrape - Fail to retrieve product list

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am reaching out because I am having some troubles to adjust a piece of code that is supposed to scrape some information from Amazon product pages (title, url, product name, etc.). Classic stuff for scraping training :)

So I basically wrote through different function:

1. One function to generate the URL to scrape
2. One function to navigate across the different element & made the value extracts

At the end I just run my driver & beautifulsoup & launch the two functions.

However, the outcome is not what I expect. I'd like to retrieve an organized csv file with 1 row per product retrieved & each associated information into columns. Nevertheless, I always end up with 1 or 2 rows, but not all products from all pages.

I assume this is something coming from my soup along with the "for loop" that is not properly going through all items (though I can't figure out what exactly).

I'd like to get your opinion about this, do you have any clues?

Thank you very much for the help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

#Function to generate URL with search KW & page nb
def get_url(search_term,page):
    template = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k={}&page='+str(page)
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+')
    url = template.format(search_term)

    return url

#Function to retrieve all data from the page
def extract_record(item):
    atag = item.h2.a
    
    #Retrieve product name
    description = atag.text.strip()
    
    #Retrieve product URL
    url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk' + atag.get('href')
    
    #Retrieve sponsored status
    try:
        sponso_parent = item.find('span','s-label-popover-default')
        sponso = sponso_parent.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-mini a-color-secondary', 'dir': 'auto'}).text
    except AttributeError:
        sponso = 'No' 

    #Retrieve price info
    try:
        price_parent = item.find('span','a-price')
        price = price_parent.find('span','a-offscreen').text
    except AttributeError:
        return
    
    #Retrieve avg product rating
    try:
        rating = item.i.text
    except AttributeError:
        rating = ''
    
    #Retrieve review count (if monetary value, nill it due to missing value)
    try:
        review_count = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base', 'dir': 'auto'}).text
    except AttributeError:
        review_count = ''
    
    if "£" in review_count or "€" in review_count or "$" in review_count:
        review_count = 0
    
    result = (url, description, sponso, price, rating,  review_count)
    
    return result
        
record_final = []

#Loop through page nb
for page in range(1,3):
    url = get_url('laptop',page)
    print(url)
    
    #Instantiate web driver & retrieve page content with BS (then loop through every product)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('\\Users\\rapha\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    final_soup = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
    
    try:
        for item in final_soup:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record:
                record_final.append(record)
    except AttributeError:
        print('error_record')
    
    driver.close()

with open('resultsamz.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['url', 'description', 'sponso', 'price', 'rating','review_count'])
    writer.writerow(record_final)
```

Comment: There is a `Accept cookies` pop-up on both the pages. Your code doesn't seem to take care of that,

Comment: How does that prevent to execute what I described?

Despite the cookie banner, the source code retrieved by BS seem normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over your final record to save each iten in a row.

Change this:

```
writer.writerow(record_final)
```

For this:

```
for item in record_final:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what you have told it to do.

`# Retrieve review count (if monetary value, nill it due to missing value)`

This is what you are getting

```
('https://www.amazon.co.uk/G-Anica%C2%AE-Portable-Ultrabook-Earphone-Accessories/dp/B08FCFDPVF/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=laptop&qid=1606453924&sr=8-10', 'G-Anica® Netbook Laptop PC 10 inch Android Portable Ultrabook,Dual Core, Wifi,with Laptop Bag + Mouse + Mouse Pad + Earphone (4 PCS Computer Accessories) (Pink)', 'No', '£119.99', '3.4 out of 5 stars', '21')
('https://www.amazon.co.uk/CHERRY%C2%AE-Notebook-Netbook-Computer-Keyboard/dp/B07ZPW7R14/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=laptop&qid=1606453924&sr=8-11', 'FANCY CHERRY® NEW 2018 HD 10 inch Mini Laptop Notebook Netbook Tablet Computer 1G DDR3 8GB Memory VIA WM8880 CPU Dual Core Android Screen Wifi Camera Keyboard USB HDMI (Black 8GB)', 'No', '£109.99', '3.3 out of 5 stars', '111')
None
None
None
None
None
https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=laptop&page=2
```

Now, if you visit the page, there are many laptops without the price. Your code is skipping those as you told it to.